# (js): dynamically import modules

Tags: javascript, import, export, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I am building the project structure and I was creating some modules, where I needed to import according to the route the user is on.

```
# my folder structure

modules
-- user
-- client
-- index
```

```js
# my code 

// get constructor 
const  const constructor = await getConstructor( 'user' ); // get the constructor

// index
export const getConstructor = async ( module ) => {
    const constructor = await require(`./${module}`).create; // option 1 
    const constructor = await import(`./${module}`).then( constructor => constructor.create ); // option 2
    return constructor;
}


// module - user
const create = ( data ) => {
    // behavior
    // ...

}

export {
    create,
    delete,
    otherFunctions
}
```

My question is what is the best way, in terms of performance, to dynamically import the `create` function, whether option 1 or 2 or even if there is another way.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can I deduce from your problem that you want to `import` some stuff on demand ?

Comment: basically, in the user file, for example, there would be some functions, such as `create`, `delete`, other functions. And on that driver, I just wanted to get the `create` function, without getting the rest. I'm thinking, in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at [es-module loader](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es-module-loader), it is a way for managing asynchronous imports 'Lazy loading', and in terms of performance, I think also this is good solution. Which lead us to your second option.

If you are using a webpack, you can take a look of a concept called [Code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll take a look: D